# Country name from geolocation in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geocode

I'm new to Python and using Pandas dataframes.

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe of country names composed from latitude and longitude records via reverse geocoding, but I'm having some troubles.

This works perfectly, and returns name of country for one row:

```
res = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(df['latitude'][0], df['longitude'][0])
print(res.country)
```

However, when I try to get country for all columns it won't work:

```
df['country'] = (Geocoder.reverse_geocode(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])).country
```

"KeyError = 12"

I have not found anything online with a solution I can get to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: the func probably doesn't understand `Series`, try `apply`: `df['country'] = df.apply(lambda x: Geocoder.reverse_geocode(x['latitude'], x['longitude']).country, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC it's likely that `reverse_geocode` doesn't understand `Series` args try `apply` to pass each row value in turn:

```
df['country'] = df.apply(lambda x: Geocoder.reverse_geocode(x['latitude'], x['longitude']).country, axis=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with dataframe as large as mine.

Comment: doesn't work is not a complete explanation, post raw data, your code, and what 'doesn't seem to work' actually means

Comment: Sorry. It means when I take a smaller version of the dataframe (c.a. 50 rows), it takes a little time but works perfectly. On my actual dataframe (thousands of rows) it takes forever, then returns query over limit response.

Comment: That is a library limitation I believe nothing to do with this code. I think you're limited in the number of requests, that's a separate issue to your original problem

Comment: which library are you using for reverse_geocoding ? Like @EdChum  I think  you're limited by the number of requests, so maybe you could use a library that enables offline queries such as this one : https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder